# Is it a correct to use passive voice in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice

Grammarly.com keeps warning me about passive voice. For example, in the following sentence it tells that I misused passive voice.

> The long-standing problem of anti-social behaviour of some youngsters
> **should be solved**. It cannot, however, **be solved** by confinement.

I do not know who should solve this problem. So I used passive voice. Is it wrong?

Comment: It's fine. Don't take grammar checkers too seriously. They are in their infancy

Comment: I have more of a problem with the ambiguity of the sentence. Does it mean that someone should solve the problem, or that the problem should already be solved? Although the next sentence is only consistent with the first interpretation.

Comment: @gotube old enough to drink--[Microsoft included a grammar checker in Word in 1992](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar_checker)--and yet, indeed, still in their infancy nonetheless!

Comment: I don't see any rules being broken here. However, the object of the first sentence (the "long-standing problem of anti-social behavior of some youngsters") seems a little wordy-- like you're trying to pack too much information into the object's label. If you restructure the sentence so that it has only one instance of the word "of", I think it will help. For example: "The anti-social behavior of some youngsters is a long-standing problem that should be solved."

Comment: It's the ambiguity pointed out by Barmar that makes the passive voice suboptimal in some situations. I write a lot of specifications and similar technical documents and forcing myself to use the active voice has helped me write more comprehensibly and precisely.

Comment: Changing 'should be solved' to 'needs solving' removes the ambiguity, but is still PV.

Comment: Your sentence states that the problem of anti-social behaviour HAS LIKELY BEEN SOLVED, which I am quite sure is not what you intended. It's like saying "According to the schedule, the building should be completed". I believe you actually wanted to say "*The long-standing problem of anti-social behaviour of some youngsters needs to be solved.*"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Grammar checkers cannot know when the passive voice is appropriate or not. In many cases, they can't even identify the passive correctly. You should always treat such advice skeptically.

Even worse, simple-minded style guides like *The Elements of Style* have convinced many writers and educators that the passive voice is always bad, when of course that is false. So advice from native speakers about the passive voice cannot always be trusted.

You seem to have identified the appropriate guideline. If the agent of **solve** is irrelevant to the context or cannot be known, then the passive might be the best choice.

Furthermore, if the *topic* of the passage is **problem**, then a structure that makes **problem** the grammatical subject is probably a good choice.

Comment: The *very first* sentences in *Elements of Style* are: "1. Form the possessive singular of nouns by adding 's. Follow this rule whatever the final consonant. Thus write write, Charles's friend Burns's poems the witch's malice Exceptions are the possessives of ancient proper names ending -es and -is, the possessive Jesus', and such forms as for conscience' sake, for righteousness' sake. But such forms as Moses' Laws, Isis' temple **are commonly replaced** by ..."

Comment: I had to take a technical writing course in college where passive voice was strictly forbidden and that was the hardest thing about the course for me.  The main reason given was that it was harder for non-native speakers to understand.  While I think it's a good to learn how to write without (or limiting) passive voice, this is correct, passive voice is a totally normal part of English.

Comment: @JimmyJames do you understand anything about the motive for forbidding PV in that course?

Comment: @OmarL The only reason I recall was that according to teacher, readers whose first language is not English can find passive voice hard to understand.  I'm not sure that's true in general but passive voice does add a lot of 'noise' in most cases.  For example "the answer has been written by Jeffrey' versus 'Jeffery wrote the answer'.  The passive version has extra words that don't really contribute to meaning and somewhat peculiar verb tense.  There are phrases where passive voice adds meaning, though.  I think the point in the course was becoming aware of how often we use passive voice.

Answer (score 12):

Your sentences are both fine.  You *could* replace the second one with

> Confinement, however, cannot solve it.

My opinion is that this is neither better nor worse than your version.

My suggestion would be to stop using Grammarly, or at least be prepared to ignore it occasionally.

Comment: I really like this.  After a big, long passive voice sentence, a short, to the point, active voice sentence punches up the conclusion.

Comment: Yes, it even "justifies" using the passive voice the first time around, to create a sort of suspense in the reader's mind: I wonder who will solve it. Answer: not confinement.

Answer (score 3):

You could have written;

'Someone should solve the long-standing problem of anti-social behaviour of some youngsters. However, confinement is not the solution.'

I prefer your version of the first sentence.  My suggestion for the second avoids repeating the 'be solved' construction.  Sometimes repetition adds useful emphasis, sometimes it jars as merely repetitive.  Your call!

(In the preceding paragraph, I first wrote 'My version of the second...' then changed it to 'My suggestion for the second...'.     Do you see why?   Do you agree?  You don't have to!)

Word's grammar checker doesn't go in for this depth of analysis.  It just detects a passive construction and flags it as possibly unnecessary.  Very often this is a helpful heads-up.  But it's a suggestion, not an instruction.

Comment: I find your example a bit weird, because your first sentence refers to a person, but the second refers to a methodology. The "however" seems a bit misplaced.

Comment: Well, it's all very well bleating that a problem should be solved.  But, when you come down to it, SOMEONE has to do the solving!   All fair comment though, and way beyond the level of a grammar checker.  Which was the main point.

Comment: Some**one** can't solve societal problems.

Comment: So who can?  The proverbial 'they'?   SomeONE can instigate a policy.  Else why do we have politicians?  (OK, don't answer that!)

Comment: @LaurencePayne Don't get me wrong, I agree with you that the passive voice here sounds better.

Answer (score 2):

> Grammarly.com keeps warning me about passive voice. For example, in the following sentence it tells that I misused passive voice.

No, it just tells you that you used it. Grammarly does not have the capability of distinguishing proper use of passive voice from its misuse.

That said, I find the phrasing a bit awkward, but not because it's passive voice. A problem is, by definition, something that should be solved, so saying "this is a problem that should be solved" is redundant. Also, "some youngsters" is rather vague. A better phrasing would be "There is a long-standing problem of anti-social behavio[u]r among youngsters. This problem cannot, however, be solved by confinement."

Comment: “A problem is, by definition, something that should be solved” – disagree. Many problems can, should, or need not be solved. “We might do _A_, but this would cause problems _X_ and _Y_, so we do _B_ instead.” “Attackers would have a lot of problems if they tried to breach our firewall.” “Finding an algorithm that does _Z_ would amount to solving the [halting problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).”